# adding flask expression using url_for dynamically in javascript to display a img element

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to append a img element in ajax POST request success for my flask application as below:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/image",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(pred_path),
                success: function() {
                $('span#predimage').append("<img src='{{ url_for('new_send') }}' width='1140' height='700'>");

                    error: function(request,status,message) {
            //alert("Error\n"+message);
            }
        });
```

The element is called correctly and the output in HTML element looks like below:

```
<span id="predimage"><img src="{{ url_for(" new_send')="" }}'="" height="700" width="1140"></span>
```

Because of which the image is not getting displayed on the webpage. can someone please help me here as i couldn't find any proper solution . Reference for the above is taken from https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/6di61d/url_for_and_jqueryjavascript/ which says the similar usage worked. But i cannot understand why it is not working here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that flask is a Backend framework.
This means that when a Client makes a request for a page, flask will take care of rendering such page and returning it to the client.
Functions like "url_for" are pretty useful to personalize your page when it is rendering.

With this said, after flask returns the rendered page, he has no way of changing anything on it.
When you add the "url_for" on JavaScript your are adding it on an already rendered page. This happens in client-side and flask is not aware of this.

Comment: Thanks very much for above asergio. In that case, when I'm trying to give SRC="file:///programming/......" On the HTML page, image is not getting rendered as well. But the same path mentioned above opens the image when given in webpage. Please help me as I m new to flask and web development.

Comment: This really depends on you are trying to do. Anyway, you should start by making flask serve static files. Make sure you have the image you want inside the static folder on your project and test if flask is serving it to you by requesting its path "localhost:5000/static/myimage.jpg". If it works, you simply have to use this path on the SRC of your image.

Comment: Sorry for trouble but I don't want to serve from static folder. Yes, my application worked with static but I have absolute paths of images located in a shared server. I want to access those files from my flask application.

Comment: I am having trouble to understand clearly your situation. I think this problem deserves a new question where you share the code you have right now and the tree of your project files.